# Adding multiple Hubspot forms on a single page in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I was trying to add multiple Hubspot forms on a vue page but only one form was loading at a time.

This is how I was trying to append a single Hubspot form.

```
mounted() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.addEventListener("load", () => {
      if (window.hbspt) {
        window.hbspt.forms.create({
          portalId: "1791848",
          formId: "ffad341d-b632-4280-a0c7-7141007bac69",
          target: "#hubspotForm",
        });
      }
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Although after wondering a lot find a really easy solution where you just have to loop through the `hbspt.forms.create` function and pass the individual object for your desired element.

```js
beforeMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.addEventListener("load", () => {
        if (window.hbspt) {
          const forms = [
            {
              portalId: "XXXXX",
              formId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              target: "#hubspotForm1",
            },
            {
              portalId: "XXXXX",
              formId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              target: "#hubspotForm2",
            },
            {
              portalId: "XXXXX",
              formId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
              target: "#hubspotForm3",
            },
          ];
          forms.forEach(form => {
            window.hbspt.forms.create(form);
          });
        }
    });
  },
```